# Interest rate for multiple lenders

Tags: java, math, finance, amortization

I want to create a [Amortisation calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization_calculator) to obtain a quote from a number *N* of lenders for 36 month loans where each lender have a different interest rate. The goal is to provide as **low** a rate as possible and provide the monthly repayment amount and the total repayment amount. The result of my code is **close but not exact**.

I am using the formula [image: formula]

calculating `i` (the interest rate) as `total amount lended / requested amount`, where the total amount lended is the money lended per each of  lender multiply by the lender's rate.

```
    BigDecimal requestedAmountP = new BigDecimal("" + requestedAmount);
    BigDecimal minLendersRate = calculateRate(requestedAmount, lenders);

    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator#Monthly_payment_formula
    // r*P/(1 - (1+r)^(-N))         if r != 0
    // P/N                          if r == 0
    BigDecimal monthlyRepayment;
    if (minLendersRate.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
        monthlyRepayment = requestedAmountP.divide(DURATION_MONTHS, MathContext.DECIMAL128);
    } else {
        BigDecimal r = calculateEffectiveInterestInMonths(minLendersRate);
        BigDecimal tmp = r.add(BigDecimal.ONE).pow(-DURATION_MONTHS.intValue(), MathContext.DECIMAL128);
        BigDecimal dividend = BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(tmp);
        monthlyRepayment = r.multiply(requestedAmountP).divide(dividend, MathContext.DECIMAL128);
    }
    BigDecimal totalRepayment = monthlyRepayment.multiply(DURATION_MONTHS);
```

To calculate rate:

```
private BigDecimal calculateRate(double requestedAmount, List<Lender> lenders) {
    List<Lender> sortedLenders = lenders.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Lender::getRate)).collect(toList());
    List<BigDecimal> moneyLended = moneyLended(requestedAmount, sortedLenders);

    BigDecimal totalMoneyLended = IntStream.range(0, moneyLended.size())
            .mapToObj(index -> moneyLended.get(index).multiply(sortedLenders.get(index).getRate()))
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

    return totalMoneyLended.divide(new BigDecimal("" + requestedAmount), MathContext.DECIMAL128);
}

private List<BigDecimal> moneyLended(double requestedAmount, List<Lender> sortedLenders) {
    List<BigDecimal> moneyLended = new ArrayList<>(sortedLenders.size());

    int i = 0;
    Double remaining = requestedAmount;
    while (remaining > 0) {
        if (remaining - sortedLenders.get(i).getAvailable().doubleValue() >= 0) {
            remaining = remaining - sortedLenders.get(i).getAvailable().doubleValue();

        } else {
            remaining = 0d;
        }
        moneyLended.add(sortedLenders.get(i).getAvailable());
        i++;
    }
    return moneyLended;
}
```

To calculate [Effective Interest in Months](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation)

```
private BigDecimal calculateEffectiveInterestInMonths(BigDecimal nominalInterest) {
    // Formula: ((1+nominalInterest)^(1/12))-1
    BigDecimal exp = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(new BigDecimal("12"), MathContext.DECIMAL128);
    return BigDecimalMath.pow(BigDecimal.ONE.add(nominalInterest), exp, MathContext.DECIMAL128)
            .subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
}
```

It seems there is a problem with **decimal** operations but I can't spot where.

Comment: Why what? You haven't described what your issue is. You say that the result is close but not exact but what result is that? Which part of the code is returning an incorrect result and what does it return vs what did you expect?

Comment: It seems there is a incorrect use of the decimal approximation.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback @JoakimDanielson